# Magento 2 Allowed Countries Admin Issue

Tags: adminform, customer-address, countries, magento2.3.3

Magento ver. 2.3.3

Choose a few allowed countries.

Then go to Customer Address Edit Form in Admin area.

Country dropdown is not as we expected.

If I just use 1 country none will show up if you chose more then it will just take countries from the top.

Anyone had this issue ad anyone solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open the below path file.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component
```

open `customer_address_form.xml` and remove below code from line number.194

```
             <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
```

Remove the above code from the file and move this file to a local folder like below.

```
 app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml
```

After remove that you will see your selected country into customer address edit in M2.

Comment: It works, but I cannot do it by override in custom module.